# Database driven ios app - first steps

Tags: iphone, ios, flash, ipad, air

I'm about to start work on my first app which will be an internal release to gather customer information at a trade show.

I'm hopefully looking into using air for ios or maybe one of the various html/js frameworks to develop this app as an alternative to learning C.

ideally I would do it with some server based php > sql to store and share gathered information between a fleet of iPads, unfortunately due to the population of this trade show there will be no guarantee that i can maintain a wireless connection so need to prepare for these apps all being local access only.

in which case, how would you recommend going about the saving/reading of the stored data, and also how to sync it up with a sql server and then back to the iPads each night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/)? It is an HTML5 app platform that allows you to author native applications with web technologies, in other words it will let you make an iphone app without having to learn C.

People have written [tutorials](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494756/Adding-SQL-Database-support-to-your-iPhone-App) and plugins for storing data locally.

PhoneGap basically wraps a web app hence you can use AJAX for sync with server as and when needed. [This](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/42450600/PhoneGap%20Ajax%20Sample) article might help.

We explored PhoneGap and found it very useful. and easy too. hope this helps you.

Comment: looks like a pretty good match for what i'm interested in. thanks